# Changing ViewController programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

I have been looking for a solution to this for quite some time but I still fail to see what the best solution is: 
*I am trying to swap view controllers programmatically, without anything in the storyboard, pure swift files.*

As far as I see  `presentViewController()` just creates a 'modal' which would cause the previous ViewController to stay in the memory (tested this, `deinit` never fires for the first controller). The solution I have found is to switch the rootViewController: `self.view.window?.rootViewController = ViewController2()` -> this fires `deinit` of the first one.

While this solution would work in theory, I am wondering...

1. Is there some recommended way or best practice of how to do this programmatically? Or is it really just about changing the `viewRootController`'s value?
2. How do you structure your app? Do you use one ViewController and you swap views? Or you present other ViewControllers as modals with presentViewController? (I am totally new to this and I can't seem to find any good source; most of the articles deal with storyboard)

Thanks a lot!

EDIT: I will add: my test app is not supposed to have any kind of navigation for different viewcontrollers (no tabs, nor anything like that). It basically works like screen1->screen2->screen3->screen4. If a reset button is pressed, it gets back to screen1. I am purely interested of swapping ViewControllers, nothing else.

Comment: It really depends on how you want to structure the navigation in your app

Answer (score 0):

1: Changing the main window's root view controller is correct for swapping view controllers.

2: Generally, swapping view controller is not used. You can use a navigation controller that has a root view controller (eg. your main screen) and then push other view controllers as needed. Tab bar view controllers are also very useful.
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewControllerCatalog/Chapters/CombiningViewControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011313-CH6-SW1

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

1.
The basic ways are:

```
navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)
```

or just pop to root view

```
navigationController?.popToRootViewControllerAnimated(true)
```

pushing can be done similarly

or setting a new stack

```
navigationController?.setViewControllers([viewController], animated: true)
```

These are the recommended ways of navigating in code just pick the one appropriate to your specific situation.

The push and pop mechanism is probably the most recommended way of doing general navigation.

2. Try to always use navigation controllers and only use modal views when appropriate.

Use navigation controllers when navigating through your main views. Modal views can be used as side views or extension to the view presenting that view modally.

**Edit:**
There are many ways of efficiency navigating through an app. In this particular case pushing and popping the navigation stack is probably the best way to go. But keep in mind that there are Tab bar controllers, collection views and others. At the end of the day The best is to look at your app structure and based on that decide which navigation method is the best for you.

Comment: This is how you can use a navigation controller, but there are lots of ways of structuring an app without a navigation controller

Comment: There are, I'm sorry I didn't cover all of them, but he asked for recommended ways. Navigation controllers are the standard apple recommend way of doing most navigation, I feel the down vote was unnecessary.

Comment: The question is too broad really.  Yes, navigation controllers are a recommended way of navigating but it is really point 2 that I have an issue with - I think you mean to avoid modal presentation unless necessary, fair enough, but it is incorrect to say "always use navigation controllers".  There are tab contollers, collection views, any number of ways of presenting view controllers.  Even modifying the root view controller is OK

Comment: You are correct, I see I could have used other words. I will edit my answer thank you.